# How to pass command line parameters like -X and -B to rtMavenRun in Artifactory Maven Plugin?

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

In my declarative Jenkinsfile, I am invoking maven with this block sourced from https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins

> ```
>            rtMavenRun (
>                 tool: 'maven-3.6.0',
>                 pom: 'pom.xml',
>                 goals: 'clean test',
>                 resolverId: 'maven-resolver-id',
>                 deployerId: 'maven-deployer-id',
>                 buildNumber: '99',
>                 buildName: 'my-build'
>             )
> ```

When it runs, the output is flooded with lots of 'Progress' entries.
The way to turn that off is the use -B on the mvn command line.

How to do so using rtMavenRun() ?

I tried using the 'options:' parameter found 
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/artifactory/#rtmavenrun-run-artifactory-maven
but that only defines JVM parameters rather than maven parameters.

Comment: Can you change the 'goals' parameter to have value '-B clean test'?

Comment: @user944849 that did it!  submit an answer and you get the credit. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the 'goals' parameter to have value `'-B clean test'`.